# UDP to server does not work

Tags: udp, udpclient

At work, I have to route some data that are coming in using UDP. I've followed some tutorials such as [this blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/simple-udp-example-code?forum=netfxnetcom) or [this tutorial](http://www.jefclaes.be/2010/03/listening-for-udp-packets-in-windows.html) and cooked up two console applications, one to send UDP messages (client) and one to read them (listener). 
When I enter the IP address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) everything goes well, but no other address works. If I use my real local IP address, I have no luck. Since I locally do not have a static IP, I've also tried installing the listener on a server that does have a static IP. In doing so, I've made sure to add a rule to the Windows Firewall inbound rules set. Still no luck. Any ideas? Here's my code:

/simon/

Client

```
    class Client
{
    private readonly Socket _sendingSocket;
    private readonly IPEndPoint _receiverEndpoint;
    private static int outboundPortNumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutgoingPortNumber"]);

    public Client()
    {
        var receiverAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IpOfReceiver"]);
        _receiverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(receiverAddress, outboundPortNumber);
        _sendingSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        _sendingSocket.EnableBroadcast = true;
    }

    public void Transmit()
    {
        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hit q to quit");
            var keypress = Console.ReadKey();

            if (keypress.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() == "q")
                done = true;
            else
                SendTextToServer();
        }
    }

    private void SendTextToServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter text to send");
        var textToSend = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);
        try
        {
            _sendingSocket.SendTo(send_buffer, _receiverEndpoint);
        }
        catch (Exception send_exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Exception {0}", send_exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Listener

```
   class Listener
{
    private bool _started;
    private ManualResetEvent _stop;
    private UdpClient _client;
    private IPEndPoint _endPoint;
    private Thread _workingThread;

    private static int inboundPortNumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncomingPortNumber"]); 

    public void Start()
    {
        _started = true;
        _stop = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        InitializeUdpClient();
        InitializeWorkingThread();
    }

    private void InitializeUdpClient()
    {
        _endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, inboundPortNumber);
        _client = new UdpClient(_endPoint);
    }

    private void InitializeWorkingThread()
    {
        _workingThread = new Thread(WorkerFunction);
        _workingThread.Name = "WorkingThread";
        _workingThread.Start();
    }

    private void WorkerFunction()
    {
        while (_started)
        {
            var res = _client.BeginReceive(iar =>
            {
                if (iar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    byte[] receivedBytes = _client.EndReceive(iar, ref _endPoint);
                    OutputToConsole(receivedBytes);


                }
            }, null);

            if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _stop, res.AsyncWaitHandle }) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OutputToConsole(byte[] receivedBytes)
    {
        string receivedPacket = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} received at {1}", receivedPacket, DateTime.Now.ToString("hhMMss.ffff"));
    }
}
```

--Edit --

One of the comments suggested that I should look at some logging. Using Microsoft Network Monitor to capture my data traffic, I've tried the following:
(1) On dev machine: When sending to 127.0.0.1 from my dev machine (so from localhost to localhost) no data is logged. I find that to be strange since this is the only scenario in which the messages are received and nicely printed out to the console.
(2) When I send from my dev machine to the server, there is some outbound data captured on my dev machine and on the server there is also incoming data. I've run netstat -b on the server, which does not show any UDP protocol at all. Since in method InitializeUdpClient() the UdpClient is with an IPEndpoint so I should be bound to the port. Why then does it not show up when I run netstat? Based on this new info, have a suggestion as to why the listener does not receive any data?

/simon/

Comment: What do your troubleshooting packet captures look like?

Comment: Your error report consists of nothing but phrases like "does not work" or "have no luck". What happens? Do you get errors? Do the sockets get created?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the problem was somehow related to the firewall. I had enabled set the nibound rules on the server and outbound rules on my development machine, but a company proxy silently blocked the traffic. When switching over to the wireless network for guests, it my traffic arrived on the server.

Simon